# Delete _ and - characters using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I am trying to convert `2015-06-03_18-05-30` to `20150603180530` using sed.

I have this:

```
$ var='2015-06-03_18-05-30'
$ echo $var | sed 's/\-\|\_//g'
$ echo $var | sed 's/-|_//g'
```

None of these are working. Why is the alternation not working?

Comment: In general, "how do I do X using Y" is a worse question than "what's the best way to do X?", because it's assuming an answer. That answer might not be correct. Now, if you explain _why_ you want to do Y ("with only built-in tools"; "using only tools that ship with my OS"), that's sensible, and lets folks suggest other tools that fit the same restriction.

Comment: (Also, in the example here, you don't want to "substitute" these characters, you want to delete them; substituting something with an empty string is _one_ way to delete it, but not the only approach; using a word that implies a specific approach likewise excludes other approaches).

Comment: ...alternately, if your real question is "why does this regular expression syntax not work in this context?", that's a legit question, but I'd suggest asking it directly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't fully agree with your first comment. I agree the idea in general but not in the case of SO people work, i mean that every time someone ask *how to do this*, people comment and ask to put code and not to ask *howto* (with often a close action *too broad* or *unclear*). Seems that request should thus be *I try to... with those constraint ... and I try this taht failed ...*

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, I *didn't* say not to include examples of what one has tried. Showing one's attempts using `sed`, in this case, is entirely appropriate, establishes context, and is also sufficient to prevent closure. Restricting the set of acceptable answers to only those which fulfill the OP's initial expectations as to how they would solve the problem themselves does no further good on this point. Certainly, though, I agree that legitimate environmental constraints should be included -- but in a way that makes their cause and nature clear (ie. "using only POSIX tools").

Comment: ok, i understand better the meaning of your comment and the way OP (and me) could enhance his way of request something on Stack

Answer (score 4):

As long as your script has a `#!/bin/bash` (or ksh, or zsh) shebang, don't use `sed` *or* `tr`: Your shell can do this built-in without the (comparatively large) overhead of launching any external tool:

```
var='2015-06-03_18-05-30'
echo "${var//[-_]/}"
```

That said, if you *really* want to use `sed`, the GNU extension `-r` enables ERE syntax:

```
$ sed -r -e 's/-|_//g' <<<'2015-06-03_18-05-30'
20150603180530
```

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html for a discussion of differences between BRE (default for `sed`) and ERE. That page notes, in discussing ERE extensions:

> Alternation is supported through the usual vertical bar `|`.

---

If you want to work on POSIX platforms -- with `/bin/sh` rather than bash, and no GNU extensions -- then reformulate your regex to use a character class (and, to avoid [platform-dependent compatibility issues with `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html)<sup>[1]</sup>, use `printf` instead):

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed 's/[-_]//g'
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> - See the "APPLICATION USAGE" section of that link, in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to do.

```
sed 's/[-_]//g'
```

This reads as:

1. `s`: Search
2. `/[-_]/`: for any single character matching `-` or `_`
3. `//`: replace it with nothing
4. `g`: and do that for every character in the line

Sed operates on every line by default, so this covers every instance in the file/string.

Comment: @abc: The alternation notation doesn't work because `sed` doesn't recognize extended REs unless you tell it to -- and indeed some versions of `sed` may not recognize them at all.  There are multiple dialects of regex, and `sed`'s is relatively primitive by default.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a solution using `sed`, but I offer an alternative in `tr`:

```
$ var='2015-06-03_18-05-30'
$ echo $var | tr -d '_-'
20150603180530
```

`tr` should be a little faster.

Explained:

- `tr` stands for *translate* and it can be used to replace certain characters with another ones.
- `-d` option stands for *delete* and it removes the specified characters instead of replacing them.
- `'_-'` specifies the set of characters to be removed (can also be specified as `'\-_'` but you need to escape the `-` there because it's considered another option otherwise).

Comment: Even faster would be to not use anything external to the shell at all.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
sed 's/[-_]//g'
```

The character class `[-_]` matches of the characters from the set.

Comment: Is there a formal rule around this in the documentation that I missed ?

Comment: info sed | grep -C 3 \\\\w will explain for \w (not connected with this problem)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g' YourFile
```

Could you tell me what failed on `echo $var | sed 's/\-\|\_//g'`, it works here (even if escapping `-` and `_` are not needed and assuming you use a GNU sed due to `\|` that only work in this enhanced version of sed)